# what is the difference between the first and second code?

Tags: swift

first code

```
struct Player {
    var name: String
    var number: Int
}
```

second code:

```
struct Player {
    var name: String
    var number: Int

    init(name: String, number: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}
```

what is the difference between the first and second code ?

Is there a source where I can learn these codes other than swift apple documentation?

Comment: The difference is that you wrote redundant code in the second example. At runtime there is no difference.  In structs (not in classes!) the compiler creates a *memberwise initializer* on your behalf. The Swift Language Guide is the best source you can get.

Comment: Code is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), so you can't have a code. "Pieces of code" is a common expression.

Comment: @Jessy, Agreed, "a code" is not proper usage, but "code" can also be used idiomatically to mean "a pile of code". "Is this code better than that code?" "Did you see the code that dev wrote?" or even  "how is this code different from that code?" are all idiomatically correct.

Answer (score 4):

As a practical matter, these are the same. The emit the [same assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/f1eEddz9Y) in Release mode. You can *almost* see how similar they are using `-print-ast` on the first example:

```
swiftc -print-ast player.swift

internal struct Player {
  internal var name: String
  internal var number: Int
  internal init(name: String, number: Int)
}
```

They're not *quite* the same. The `init` implementation is not written into the AST directly. It gets injected later. You can explore exactly what it does by reading the `createImplicitConstructor` implementation in the [CodeSynthesis](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/ac7a4781a675505bccb581de3dbd68fd19a719bb/lib/Sema/CodeSynthesis.cpp#L276-L329) source.

The SIL for the second example in Release is [effectively identical](https://godbolt.org/z/nf413ejvG) to the SIL for the first example in all modes. In Debug mode, they are slightly different (since one is optimized and the other is not). But in Release, the only difference is extra `debug_value` statements to give source locations to the debugger in the explicit form:

```
sil hidden @$s6output6PlayerV4name6numberACSS_SitcfC : $@convention(method) (@owned String, Int, @thin Player.Type) -> @owned Player {
bb0(%0 : $String, %1 : $Int, %2 : $@thin Player.Type):
  debug_value %0 : $String, let, name "name", argno 1, loc "/app/example.swift":5:10, scope 14 // id: %3
  debug_value %1 : $Int, let, name "number", argno 2, loc "/app/example.swift":5:24, scope 14 // id: %4
  debug_value %0 : $String, var, (name "self", loc "/app/example.swift":5:5, scope 14), implicit, type $*Player, expr op_fragment:#Player.name, loc "/app/example.swift":6:19, scope 14 // id: %5
  debug_value %1 : $Int, var, (name "self", loc "/app/example.swift":5:5, scope 14), implicit, type $*Player, expr op_fragment:#Player.number, loc "/app/example.swift":7:21, scope 14 // id: %6
  %7 = struct $Player (%0 : $String, %1 : $Int), loc "/app/example.swift":8:5, scope 15 // user: %8
  return %7 : $Player, loc "/app/example.swift":8:5, scope 15 // id: %8
} // end sil function '$s6output6PlayerV4name6numberACSS_SitcfC'
```

As a practical matter they are identical. As lorem ipsum notes, the correct place to learn this is the Swift book. It will teach you what is meant to happen. But if you want to know what really happens, then `swiftc` has many modes to show you each step of the process, and the compiler source code is available for inspection (and quite readable and organized, IMO).

Answer (score 3):

The first version has a "Memberwise Initializer" and the second version has a "Custom Initializer".

> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they don’t define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a default initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if it has stored properties that don’t have default values.

> The memberwise initializer is a shorthand way to initialize the member properties of new structure instances. Initial values for the properties of the new instance can be passed to the memberwise initializer by name.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization/

Because the Custom initializer isn't doing anything special there is no functional difference between the two options.

The documentation will always be the best place to learn. An essential skill is to be able to create and understand code straight from the documentation.